# What are the animals in these pictures?

Tags: zoology

I recently found some pictures of animals' skeletons. Does anyone know what species they are?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The pictures appear to be computationally generated or computationally enhanced visualizations (e.g.: change in color rather than in polygons around joints). Did the source perhaps include further images?

Comment: @tsttst Seems to be animal under X-ray.

Comment: @aircraft - They are not xrays. Just dramatically lit/shaded, maybe even computer generated, but not xrays.

Comment: The first, as @John said, is a water mammal: a seal, sea lion, something along those lines. The teeth are consistent with the Australian fur seal. The second, I have no clue. It's very light, fast, (I thought maybe a flying squirrel, but the 'hands' are wrong.) Seeing the teeth would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top is some kind of **seal** (the flippers give it away) and the bottom is some kind of **lemur** (the long thin limbs and tail with the narrow skull) but that is the best I can do from just those photos. It might be a flying lemur but again from just the one photo without scale is difficult to say for certain.

Comment: the <a href="https://goo.gl/images/jRXGaU">lemur</a>'s tail is longer than its trunk.

Comment: @aircraft There are many species of lemur with vastly different tail lengths, and we cant see how long the tail in the image is that well. Also your link is broken.